dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package 'libgtk-3-common' is missing final newline
When attempting to install docker, java, and curl and was receiving the entitled error for each of these.  Did manage to install curl with another method, but anything where sudo apt was used to install things gave this error.
Here is the what is coming back
$ sudo apt install default-jre   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-21-jre openjdk-21-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei | fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-21-jre openjdk-21-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/48.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 210 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package ca-certificates-java.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libgtk-3-common' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)


Look into the file /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk-3-common.list and fix it.

... or remove it and run sudo dpkg --configure -a ... then update lists with sudo apt update and reinstall with sudo apt reinstall libgtk-3-common and it should be fixed this way as well.

Look into the file /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk-3-common.list and fix it ... There, could be a missing final newline as suggested in the error message or there could be some other format abnormality ... That file should look something like this:
$ cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgtk-3-common.list 
/.
/etc
/etc/gtk-3.0
/etc/gtk-3.0/im-multipress.conf
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libgtk-3-common
/usr/share/doc/libgtk-3-common/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/libgtk-3-common/README.md
/usr/share/doc/libgtk-3-common/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libgtk-3-common/copyright
/usr/share/glib-2.0
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.ColorChooser.gschema.xml
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.Debug.gschema.xml
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.EmojiChooser.gschema.xml
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml
/usr/share/gtk-3.0
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/bn.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/da.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/de.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/es.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/et.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/fi.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/fr.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/hi.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/hu.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/it.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/ja.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/ko.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/lt.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/ms.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/nb.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/nl.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/pl.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/pt.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/ru.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/sv.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/th.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/uk.gresource
/usr/share/gtk-3.0/emoji/zh.gresource
/usr/share/themes
/usr/share/themes/Default
/usr/share/themes/Default/gtk-3.0
/usr/share/themes/Default/gtk-3.0/gtk-keys.css
/usr/share/themes/Emacs
/usr/share/themes/Emacs/gtk-3.0
/usr/share/themes/Emacs/gtk-3.0/gtk-keys.css
$

Alternatively, you can backup and remove that file and then run:
sudo dpkg --configure -a

then, run:
sudo apt update

then, reinstall with:
sudo apt reinstall libgtk-3-common

and that should fix it as well.

Great, this worked. There ended up being three .list files that I had to remove and repeat the above and then reinstall, but it is installing things now. Note, that the files would not allow me to open for editing, so removing and reinstalling was the best option in this case
